# How do I add an environment variable for a windows user

Tags: windows, batch-file

- I have a sheduling engine that runs
  jobs on windows 2003 server.
- It runs as a particular domain user.
- I don't have access to log on as the
  user but I have admin access.
- I need to be able to script storing a
  password in an environment variable
  that is specific to the user
- The user does not appear to have an
  environment on the target platform
  because HKU\SID does not exist in the
  registry for the user. (SID is the
  users domain SID)
- but it has a profile
- I cant add
  HKU\SID\Environment\VAR_NAME ....
  using reg.exe, it returns ERROR: The
  parameter is incorrect.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using roaming profiles?

Comment: No, we are not using roaming profiles

Comment: You need to explain what you mean when you say that the user has a profile on the machine, but that HKU\SID does not exist. I don't see how that can be so.

Comment: Successful Logon: User Name: mtidsql Domain: MSAD Logon ID: (0x0,0x6F5ED705) Logon Type: 4 Logon Process: Advapi Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0 Workstation Name: LPRPEST001 Logon GUID: - Caller User Name: LPRPEST001$ Caller Domain: MSAD Caller Logon ID: (0x0,0x3E7) Caller Process ID: 8152 Transited Services: - Source Network Address: - Source Port: -

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\mtidsql - exists = the profile

Comment: S-1-5-21-4186578074-3454285278-1435315062-3680 = the user SID

Comment: reg query HKU\S-1-5-21-4186578074-3454285278-1435315062-3680
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

Comment: I think you should take this question to serverfault.com since it appears to be more sysadmin than development.

Comment: Thanks - ( I had no idea it serverfault existed :))

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a login script with the SET command to create the environment variable?

Comment: I'll give it a try, nice and simple!

Comment: @Paddy Carrol -- you mean the domain controller? If it were setup as a login script in \\DCNAME\Netlogon and the AD user's "Profile" tab, then it would not be available if the domain controllers were down (God forbid!). But if it were a script that exists on the computer locally (either in the Start Menu's "Startup" folder for interactive logins, or in a GPO which would be cached when the DC is unavailable) then it could still run.